# loose folder in web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks

i updated a website with asp.net and c# from framework .net 2.0 to 4.5.1. (I'm using VS2013 Professional Update 4).

I've rebuilded and resolved all errors; (now there are no errors or warnings).
But when i started debug i noticed i loose something:
the complete address

http://localhost:2201/WebSiteName/folder/filename.aspx
became
http://localhost:2201/folder/filename.aspx.

it isn't possible to update virtual url in a web site (only in a web application).

I don't understand if it depend from new web browser (IIS Express in VS2013).
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: I think this is in Project/Properties/Web menu, where you can set the virtual path

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 uses  IIS Express 8.0 and set as main default root the website folder (i mean the real folder where we made our site).

to use this folder in the url you change:

c:\user[username]\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

and to find block tag who refer to the website.

copy tag "Application" set new values.

L'applicationPool is set to "Classic" for WebSite while "Integrated" for the WebApplication.

```
<site name="Prova" id="5">
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4ClassicAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\prova" />
</application>
<application path="/MyRoot" applicationPool="Clr4ClassicAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\prova/myRoot" />
</application>
        <bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2001:localhost" />
                </bindings>
</site>
```